# How can I use Google Benchmark on godbolt

Tags: c++, gcc

I am trying to run some code on that uses Google Benchmark. I am trying to share it with some colleagues using Godbolt. It seems to support Google Benchmark as a library you can select but I can not get it to compile.

This is the link.
https://godbolt.org/z/dxvl5W

It is using gcc 7.3 with these options:
`-std=c++17 -O3 -lbenchmark`

I tried adding `-lbenchmark` and `-lbenachmark-main`. None resolve the issue.

This is the error I am getting

```
ASM generation compiler returned: 0

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lbenchmark

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Execution build compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: http://quick-bench.com/ is a better bet - it's built upon google bench

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Godbolt himself confirmed that godbolt.org can not link with google benchmark. Only compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I use Google Benchmark on godbolt

As it stands - you can't.

Answer (score 2):

Godbolt lets you #include by url.

```
#include "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/benchmark/master/include/benchmark/benchmark.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use quick-bench to microbenchmark. Just click the quick-bench link in godbolt or go to: https://quick-bench.com/ It supports google benchmark.

For your code sample:
https://quick-bench.com/q/X4VuveQHPfc8fFrk8sbbMEoVVx0